# Add a unique id to a processing instruction (xsl)

Tags: xml, xslt, processing-instruction

I would like to rename a processing instruction, and at the same time add a unique id attribute to it. My input looks like this:

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<material xml:lang="en-us">
  <title>
    <?PI_start author="joepublic" comment="Comment #1" ?>Discovering
      <?PI_end?>XML
  </title>
  <related-stuff>
    <?PI_start author="johndoe" comment="Comment #3" ?>
      <a href="otherdoc.xml" />
      <?PI_end?>
  </related-stuff>
</material>
```

The result would look like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<material xml:lang="en-us">
  <title>
    <?otherPI_start author="joepublic" comment="Comment #1" id ="1" ?>Discovering
    <?otherPI_end id ="1" ?>XML
  </title>
  <related-stuff>
    <?otherPI_start author="johndoe" comment="Comment #3" id ="2" ?>
    <a href="otherdoc.xml" />
    <?otherPI_end id ="2"?>
  </related-stuff>
</material>
```

Notice that I have two id's generated, id="1" for the first instruction encountered in the document, id="2" for the second.
Also notice that the id is repeated in the otherPI_end processing instruction.

Can you help me identify the matching statement in the xsl that would do this?

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_start')">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="otherPI_start">
      author="<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'author=&quot;'),'&quot;')"/>"
      comment="<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'comment=&quot;'),'&quot;')"/>"
      id="<!-- What should I put here??? -->"
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_end')">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="otherPI_end">
      id="<!-- What should I put there??? -->"
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `id="<!-- What should I put here??? -->"`

```
<xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
```

---

If you want the id of `<?PI_end?>` to match that of the preceding `<?PI_start ?>`, then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_start')[1])"/>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_start')">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="otherPI_start">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>id="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_end')">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="otherPI_end">
        <xsl:text>id="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_start')[1])"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `xsl:number` here

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_start')">
<xsl:processing-instruction name="otherPI_start">
  author="<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'author=&quot;'),'&quot;')"/>"
  comment="<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'comment=&quot;'),'&quot;')"/>"
    id="<xsl:number count="processing-instruction('PI_start')" level="any" />"
</xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>
```

If you find this does not count the current processing instruction (which would mean the numbering starting at zero), try this instead....

```
<xsl:number count="/|processing-instruction('PI_start')" level="any" />
```

Comment: Why do you say "This won't count the current processing instruction though"? I am not sure I have ever numbered pis before but I don't see why `xsl:number` would behave differently from numbering elements. And when I test your snippet with `<xsl:number count="processing-instruction('PI_start')" level="any" />` with Saxon 6.5.5 the number starts with `1`.

Comment: With  http://xsltransform.net/ being down again, I was http://www.xslfiddle.net/ which did start the numbering at 0. I've re-worded my answer to make this a bit more clear.

Comment: Hmm, starting with zero seems to be a bug in Chrome and libxslt.